# Turn copied SVN branch into real branch

Tags: svn

A user wrongly created a subversion branch via normal copy instead of via `svn copy`, so there is no ancestry.  Is there a way to fix it and make it  a real svn branch with all its history?

Comment: What is a "normal copy"? Something like `cp -r ./my_branch ./new_branch`?

Comment: yes users used windows copy not svn copy

Comment: @user3544428 windows copy does not generate SVN branches. A commit goes to the original source of the copy (i.e. old branch/trunk). If it was that way you would have to sort out things in the SVN repository. Or did he just do a new import of the code? If yes, then you will not get history.

Comment: FYI and JIC: it seems that this is the same question as posted on LinkedIn https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/157593-5995607767497326594?trk=groups-post-b-title